# Difference between Consecutive rows for different unique id's

Tags: mysql

[image]I working on a problem where I want the difference between Avg_price for  consecutive rows for different ids in sql

I want the Null or zero value when it starts for new id in sql.

I want the o/p column as zero value for id starting with 2 and 3 and similarly.

I have tried partition by, but was unsuccessful.

```
SET @tmp := -1;

SELECT @n := @n + 1 n,W.*,if(@tmp =-1, 0, W.Avg_price - @tmp) as 'o/p',@tmp:=W.Avg_price as dummy   
  from (  
  Select A.id,A.year, A.Avg_price       
    from     
    (Select products.id,substring(orders.placed_on,1,4) as year, Avg(order_items.price ) as Avg_price 
     from 
     order_items 
     Inner Join orders
     ON order_items.order = orders.id 
     Inner Join product_variations 
     ON product_variations.id = order_items.product_variation 
     Inner Join products 
     ON products.id = product_variations.product 
     Group By products.id,substring(orders.placed_on,1,4)
    ) as A 
  ) as W,(SELECT @n := 0) m ;
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Please take a few moments and properly format your question.  Add _four_ or more spaces to each line of actual code, to give it a clean monospaced format.

Comment: The question is more readable now.

Comment: Can you provide everything as text, please? We can't copy anything from pictures.

Comment: Have changed the image to text.